# THREE.JS Update vertices in Particle System

Tags: javascript, three.js

im new to threejs and im trying to move my points in a simple particle system but it does not do anything.
ive been surfing web for 4 houts still nothing, and i begin to hate threejs more and more.

```
particles = new THREE.Geometry();
material = new THREE.ParticleBasicMaterial();
for(var count = 0; count < 1000; count++){

p_x = Math.random() * 1000 - 500;

p_y = Math.random() * 1000 - 500;

p_z = Math.random() * 1000 - 500;

particle = new THREE.Vector3(p_x, p_y, p_z);

particles.vertices.push(particle);

  }
particle_system = new THREE.Points(particles, material);

scene.add(particle_system);

particle_system.geometry.dynamic = true;
//renderer
}

  function animate() {
  var index = 0;

  while(index < 1000){
        particle_system.geometry.verticesNeedUpdate = true;


//THESE 3 LINES BELLOW CAUSE THE ERROR

particles.vertices[index].position.x += Math.random() * 1000 - 500;

particles.vertices[index].position.y += Math.random() * 1000 - 500;

particles.vertices[index].position.z += Math.random() * 1000 - 500;

 index++;

}
   requestAnimationFrame(animate);
 controls.update();
        }
```

THE ERROR IS : Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'x' of undefined
    at animate (p.html:73)
its for x,y,z.
Note : im a beginner so try to keep it simple and please dont link any site,been there trust me.

Comment: **1.** Vertices in a geometry are `THREE.Vector3()` themselves, so they don't have `.position` property. **2.** Where did you get `THREE.ParticleBasicMaterial()` from?

Comment: THREE.ParticleBasicMaterial() is the same as the new PointsMaterial.and what do u mean by vertices are three.vector3 themselvs ?

Comment: After such a powerful statement _"please dont link any site,been there trust me"_, it's very clear that you've missed just one site: https://threejs.org and its part about documentation of [this](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/core/Geometry), [this](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/math/Vector3) and [that](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/materials/PointsMaterial).

Comment: yup before u even link me fixed it , had to remove position as u said :P got another problem that have to put it on stack. thanks for the heads up prisoner849